# How realistic is the physics engine?

Tags: physics

I've been working on making a bowling animation where a character throws a bowling ball and it hits bowling pins (obviously). I showed brother my WIP and he said the only thing he didn't like about it was that the ball seems to get thrown quite far despite being heavy. I changed the mass of the ball and saw no effect but then realized that mass shouldn't effect it as such but more so the drag, I think?

Is drag automatically calculated? I tried to add a drag force but I don't know how to make it match real world physics. Assuming there's no drag being calculated then the bowling simulation I'm doing acts as if it's in a vacuum? Can someone clarify how it all works and what I can do to get more realistic results?

Comment: Like most functions in Blender, if the results don't suit, try and try again with a new method or approach.  Blender is so darned versatile there's not a lot you can't emulate in one form or another. As for it's physics, on the whole it's pretty good but there are occasions where it just plain won't do the obvious and you have to switch over to manual keyframing.  Thanks to the graph editor you can do a pretty good job of it.

Comment: Continued... In your case, the bowling ball can be switched to a duplicate and that animated or constrained to a path, any way you wish.  The original whilst invisible can be forced back into the correct trajectory for the strike. It's organized to match the duplicate at the strike frame and switched to visible again.  This is also a lot easier when there's no course pattern on the ball such as found in soccer.